# How to get CSS triangles to display in a row instead of vertical

Tags: html, css

Basically, I want a row of triangles on the top of the page. They should be down facing. I've made the triangle in CSS but for some reason they want to go up and down on top of each other and not in a row like I need them too.

Can someone with more experience in CSS please take a look? Thanks.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="triangle-container">

    <div class="arrow-down">
    </div>

    <div class="arrow-down">
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
/* BODY */

body
{
    background-color: #eee;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: none;
    border: none;
    margin: none;
}

/* Triangles! */

.triangle-container
{
    display: inline;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.arrow-down
{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-left:50px solid transparent;
    border-right:50px solid transparent;
    border-top:50px solid #FF6A00;
}
```

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ezMa7/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must apply `display:inline` to those elements which you want to be displayed inline, not their container.

In your case, it should be `inline-block`, because it should be `inline` element which behaves as `block` element. Read more **[here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)**.

---

Put `display:inline-block` for the `.arrow-down` and remove it from `.triangle-container`:

```css
.triangle-container
{
    display: inline; /* Remove this line */
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.arrow-down
{
    display: inline-block; /* Add this line */
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-left:50px solid transparent;
    border-right:50px solid transparent;
    border-top:50px solid #FF6A00;
}
```

**Live demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ezMa7/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

I added a `float:left` to your `.arrow-down` class. (and updated a couple of classes)

Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/KwKe8/

Comment: For some reason while using your code I got a Euro sign displayed in the body even though it wasn't in my code. For everything else though it worked fine, but I decided against using your code because of the stray Euro Sign. Thanks a lot anyway (: