# Most cross-browser safe way to build dynamic and resuable graphical element in pure CSS, CSS/SVG or CSS/HTML5

Tags: css, html, svg

### 1. The Goal

I am working on a highly dynamic, extensible block/inline-block level element-style. It'll look like this:

[image]

### 2. What I Actually Need

Advice on choosing from amongst my options, basically. What approach is most compatible with cross-browser friendliness & extensibility as primary concerns?

I'm using SASS to render my CSS, so the `<style>` element in my example(s) is pseudocode. I want to be able to dynamically control the following with a well-defined class heirarchy:

- text content (idiosyncratic)
- height (highly variable)
- width (5 possible widths; I'm developing in Zurb's [Foundation 5](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/), the element will always be between 1 and 5 columns)
- background color (only 2-5 options here)
- color (only 3 options here)
- direction (L & R are probably adequate)

### **3. Things I've tried**

**Bitmap**

This is no good; I'd have to make too many and can't control the angle of the point as it is stretched across heights.

**Pure CSS**

This is what I expect I'll have to do.

```
<!-- the HTML -->
<div class="arrow-label">
    <h4 class="expand"><?php echo $label-text;?></h4>
    <a href="#" class="triangle right-facing"></a>
</div>

<style>
  div.arrow-label {
    h4 {
      display:inline-block;
      background-color: $arrow-label-background-color;
    }
     .triangle { background-color: $arrow-label-background-color; }
  }

.triangle {
  width:0;
  height:0;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0;
  border-style: solid;
  transition: border-color 300ms ease-out; 
  // I have removed transitional selectors (ie. :hover) below for brevity's sake

    &.up-facing {
      border-width: 0 rem-calc(12px) rem-calc(15px) rem-calc(12px);
      border-color: transparent transparent $triangle-color transparent;
    }
    // rinse/repeat for .left-facing, .right-facing, .bottom-facing

    &.disabled {
       transition:none;
       color: $triangle-disabled-color;
    }

    &.inherited-transition { transition: inherit}
  }
</style>
```

**SVG**

So I'll just confess that I only loosely understand how to harness what I know is the very powerful potential of SVG, here. I've generated this SVG in Illustrator, though I think that probably it needs to be modified in order to be as extensible as I'd like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="635.436px" height="156.041px" viewBox="0 0 635.436 156.041" enable-background="new 0 0 635.436 156.041"
     xml:space="preserve">
<polygon fill="#333333" points="576.576,155.254 635.436,78.02 576.576,0.787 576.576,0 575.976,0 575.976,0 575.976,0 0,0 
    0,156.041 576.576,156.041 "/>
</svg>
```

But don't reeeeeally understand how to use it; I gather, for example, that I cannot achieve my ends if I use it as the `background-image` property argument of an element that otherwise contains the text; but neither do I get how this is done on the fly via CSS.

### UPDATE

A comment requested the compiled CSS, here it is; I haven't checked the colors, I expect they are nonsensical at the moment, but otherwise I think this covers it:

```
/* The element itself */
div.arrow-label h4 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #323232;
}


/* the code I use to make triangles, and in this case, would be capping the element with 
   note that, as per the standard, 1rem = 16px here */
.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  transition: border-color 300ms ease-out;
}

.triangle.up-facing {
  border-width: 0 0.75rem 0.9375rem 0.75rem;
  border-color: transparent transparent #ff5555 transparent;
}

.triangle.up-facing:hover {
  border-color: transparent transparent #ffa1a1 transparent;
}

.triangle.up-facing:active {
  border-color: transparent transparent #683939 transparent;
}

.triangle.down-facing {
  border-width: 0.9375rem 0.75rem 0 0.75rem;
  border-color: #ff5555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.triangle.down-facing:hover {
  border-color: #ffa1a1 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.triangle.down-facing:active {
  border-color: #bb0000 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.triangle.right-facing {
  border-width: 0.75rem 0 0.75rem 0.9375rem;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ff5555;
}

.triangle.right-facing:hover {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ffa1a1;
}

.triangle.right-facing:active {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #683939;
}

.triangle.left-facing {
  border-width: 0.75rem 0.9375rem 0.75rem 0;
  border-color: transparent #ff5555 transparent transparent;
}

.triangle.left-facing:hover {
  border-color: transparent #ffa1a1 transparent transparent;
}

.triangle.left-facing:active {
  border-color: transparent #683939 transparent transparent;
}

.triangle.disabled {
  transition: none;
  color: #ffa1a1;
}

.triangle.inherited-transition {
  transition: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Please post your compiled CSS instead of SASS.

Comment: Ugh. I will if you can tell me how to tell grunt not to minify it. ;) j/k, I will but it'll take me a bit b/c I really don't know how to retrieve it unmolested by grunt, I'm using Foundation 5. : /

Comment: You can try copying the relevant bits into a tool like sassmeister (http://sassmeister.com/)

Comment: Nice, ty. Can you tell I'm a designer who learned to code and not the other way round? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG file (simplified code)

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 100" >
    <polygon fill="#333" points="0,0 460,0 500,50 460,100 0,100" />
</svg>
```

CSS file, or embedded with `<style>`

```
#my_block{
    width: 190px;
    height: 40px;
    background-image: url(../images/arrow.svg);/*change to the svg url*/
    background-position: right center;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    transition: 100ms 200ms ease-out;
}
#my_block:hover{
    width: 200px;
    transition: 100ms ease-out;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

HTML (the div can be an *ul*, *p*, *inline-block*,..)

```
<div id="my_block"></div>
```

Comment: When you have the <svg></svg> in html you don't need to use the xmlns=".." information.

Comment: Won't this allow contents to spill out over the background SVG (notably over the triangle bit)?

Comment: Also, won't this only cover fixed-size containers?

Comment: I already edited the bacgground-size from cover to auto 100%;

Comment: Yes, but note that container is no longer a container -- it is a *background* to a container. What is stopping the content from simply overflowing into the triangle bit of the SVG? You could set padding in the #my_block element to avoid that methinks.

Comment: Although maybe I'm just tired and not seeing it. XD

Comment: This doesn't actually leverage any of the features that make SVG powerful; could just as easily use a PNG file here. ;)

Comment: @kardaw I can't use a background-image property; the lengths & heights of elements using this style cascade aren't known; that's why I specify 52° in my image, because however I implement this, that much has to remain true; the CSS will have to be able to deploy logitech that can *build this polygon on the fly* to properly inhabit it's container.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use div "squares" and a div "triangle" that are styled with just CSS?

Triangles in Pure CSS: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Give the elements each the same height and whatever widths that you want, and it should work fine -- easy peazy.

Edit: for more on "inline CSS triangles," check out [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663190/how-to-get-css-triangles-to-display-in-a-row-instead-of-vertical).
Edit 2: Proof of concept [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pbvQb/):

HTML:

```
<div class="pointyDiv">This is le content</div>
```

CSS:

```
.pointyDiv {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:black;
    padding:50px 0px;
    color:white;
}
.pointyDiv:after {
    position: absolute;
    border: solid;
    border-color: transparent black;
    border-width: 60px 0px 60px 40px;
    content:"";
    text-align:center;
    right:-40px;
    top:0px;
}
```

And it easily [could be made responsive](http://codeitdown.com/css-triangles-responsive/) by wrapping it in a container.

Comment: That's why I put so much emphasis on "extensible"; I can do that, but I need a huge number of these, for needs not yet known; it's a generic container and so I'm not keen to do it that way because it lacks a clear strategy for building and maintaining a clear and comprehensive class hierarchy. : / Thanks though.

Comment: If you need "a huge number of these," then CSS is perfect. I don't see the issue... If you don't want to copy/paste the three lines that it would take for you to make another "generic container," just write a Javascript function to wrap anything of a particular class. : )

Comment: And in terms of a "clear and comprehensive class hierarchy," you also can't beat pure HTML/CSS if you want support on all modern browsers. Especially if you want a container, SVG is not the way to go; many frameworks/libraries don't yet play nicely with SVGs without using SVG-specific plugins (eg: jQuery). Just a warning in case you end up taking the path less traveled. ;)

Comment: Yeah, I mean you're basically describing what I'm planning to do if this doesn't present a solution, but, the demands of my current context involve passing this off, permanently, to a client who will likely need to extend it on their own, and will likely be horrible at it. I'm trying to to get to a solution wherein I can control, now, what can *and cannot* be done with it in the future. Thanks, in any case, if the answer I'm hoping exists doesn't surface I'll right-answer you in a day or so. :)

Comment: Whatever works; answer shmanswer. And if the client will "likely be horrible" at modifying the HTML and will need to do it, then I would highly advise to keep it simple by making a JavaScript wrapper for a class that the client can use whenever they want a "pointy container." The client being able to research how to fix something they broke can be just as invaluable as spending your time making the client a complex toy that "railroads them" until they manage to break it. Just speaking from experience. ;) Anyhoo! G'luck.